# Using a collector on a multi-interface generic - java

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

I have a class with a generic type:

```
class MyClass<K extends InterfaceA & InterfaceB>{...}
```

Where `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB` have `methodA` and `methodB` respectively. Both methods are of return type `String`

In this class there is `List<K>` which I process in the following way:

```
public void setList(List<K> list){
    Map<String,K> map = list
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(K::methodB, p -> p))
}
```

This fails silently and I believe this is just because the exception is not propagated. However, if I use `K::methodA` everything works.

If I swap the interface declaration of `K` as such:

```
class MyClass<K extends InterfaceB & InterfaceA>{...}
```

then the opposite is true; where `K::methodB` works and `k::MethodA` does not. It appears that the collector can only see the first interface declared for the generic.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with `util.Function` or if there is a type issue with the collector.

How can this be fixed so that any number of interfaces are visible to the collector's process?

Comment: @MikeSamuel Both `methodA` and `methodB` return `String`, hence the resulting map's key type being `String`. I will update my question to clarify. Thanks

Comment: What if you replace `K::methodB` with `p -> p.methodB()`? Any difference?

Comment: @biziclop works! So its something in the way the `<type>::<function>` syntax is interpreted? any ideas why?

Comment: @RBI Not yet, it was just a guess. :)

Comment: @biziclop I don't know why I didn't try that earlier. If you want to post an answer that we can expand on the accept is yours!

Comment: @RBI Having done some investigation, I think I'll mark this as a duplicate instead.